# Accessing windows of other processes (Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, macos-carbon

I am currently developing an Objective-C application that needs to be able to modify other windows on the current system. In detail, I am trying to set the window level of a Chrome App from within my own Cocoa App. I can get the window ID through the Carbon-API but I can't get a NSWindow handle, because it is not my own window.

I am thinking there might be a way to do it through the Accessibility API, but I can't seem to find the correct piece of code. Do you know how to do this?

Thanks!
Pedro

Comment: were you able to find a way of doing so ?